# How Kubernetes balances the load to the eks worker node

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am trying to learn about amazon eks. I have created eks cluster along with the node group. Now i want to balance the load coming to worker nodes. Do i need to explicitly add the load balancer or master control manager will take care of it by itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes comes with [kube proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-proxy/) which provides L4 layer load balancing for replica pods deployed across multiple Kubernetes worker nodes. But if you want to have more sophisticated load balancing you can use an [external LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/).

For load balancing the requests to Kubernets API Serve it's recommended to expose the the API Server endpoints to your clients via a Loadbalancer.